# Octopus Deploy On Same Machine

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I've just started using this tool and so far it seems brilliant.  I'm struggling to get my head around how to organise this in the tool though.

I have a website and an api to deploy.

I have one project set up and three environments, staging, UAT and live.

I have one tentacle with two roles all executing on my development machine.

I can see the deployments to the environments being built in the `Apps` directory.

What I'm struggling with is getting my head around how these different players should be configured.

What I'm struggling with is that on the same machine I want the two steps ( Api step, web step) to do something different based on the environment.

So when deploying api step to staging it also goes to `C:\staging\api` but when deploying to uat it goes to `C:\uat\api`.

I can't see how I can get it to do this since a step is defined separately to environments as far as I can tell.

It seems octopus deploy assumes there are at least two machines involved in which case you'd never want to do this anyway, at least I can't think you would.

Is this arrangement possible in Octo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was separating out the scripts into two bundles rather than having a bundle shared between the steps.

Eventually the bundles will contain separate scripts so this makes more sense in the long run anyway.

I then added a step for each bundle in the Octopus Deploy project.

Ideally this would be in two projects however I'm only using the trial version at the moment.

Comment: Like you, I have a website and an API to deploy, rather than deploy as one package, I keep them separate so that I can deploy each one independently. Works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [variables](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/features/variables) to achieve what you are after.